# Building remote server/api(?)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, azure

I am trying to build a remote server (or api? — what's the difference?) such that I can essentially do a fetch request to the http(s):// url in question and get back the JSON object model stored at that url. However, whenever I search for something like "build RESTful API node.js" or "build remote server node.js" I generally get a tutorial like [this](https://medium.com/@onejohi/building-a-simple-rest-api-with-nodejs-and-express-da6273ed7ca9), which seems to tell me only how to build a server that listens on a *localhost* port.

I am, if it wasn't clear, very new to node, so forgive me if this question is utterly basic: when building a remote server, am I essentially just putting something like this

```
const modelJSON = require('path/from/root/of/remote/server/repo/to/model.json');

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const CORS = require("cors");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(CORS());

let modelObj = modelJSON;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(modelObj);
});
```

In a server.js file, stored, alongside the model in question (and its shard.bin files...), in a remote repo held in Azure or AWS or something?

Comment: Each computer has a localhost and a "server" is just another computer with a localhost that is a static IP and can route incoming traffic to it's localhost... So when you build a node API you run that typically on localhost and then have something like Nginx or Apache proxy all incoming requests to your node app on localhost on a port.

Comment: An old intro to http/2 I wrote ages ago shows an nginx config with a node proxy at the bottom. It also explains to you how you would setup a new server after provisioning it and having ssh access https://gist.github.com/dominikwilkowski/435054905c3c7abc2badc92a0acff4ba

Comment: "So when you build a node API you run that typically on localhost and then have something like Nginx or Apache proxy all incoming requests to your node app on localhost on a port." — Ok, so Nginx/Apache/(Heroku?) redirect incoming requests (get, post, put, etc.) to a given port of the server, which (because of the node server.js file) is instructed to listen on that port and then to respond by serving certain data from files also contained on that server (that is, files/data contained in the same (in this case remote) directory as the server.js file). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure about Heroku etc and their setup. I would assume they have all that already setup for you and all you have to set is the part in your package.json or something. Worth a google I guess

Answer (score 0):

## The difference of server (or api ?)

**1. As receiving Http request and returning json data, these two are the same.**

**2. The difference is whether you publish your web application in paas service or vm machine.**

**1. PaaS Services**

`Azure App Services` or `Amazon Web Services` both of them are `PaaS Services`, if we host our application on `PaaS Services`, we just can use `80` and `443` port.(*Http and Https*)

In our code, we usually use `process.env.PORT || 3000` to listen http request. When your program is released, it will read environment variables according to `process.env.PORT` and listen port 80/443.

**2. VM Machine**

We can set a custom listening port(It also means you can create more applications.), any program can be installed in the server, and it can be called. For example, you can call office software, ffmpeg, etc.

## Suggestion

If you only need one application, you can use paas services, which provides a more simple maintenance interface for webapps, and can better manage web applications. And the charge is lower than VM. If the application uses the .exe file and it cannot be solved in PaaS Services, it is recommended to use the Container web app. If you really want to use VM Machine, you can choose according to actual needs.